# Adjusting dependently typed function spaces

Tags: dependent-type, lean

Suppose we have the following definition that represents a bounded integer in clopen interval `<a, b)`.

```
def zbound (x₁ x₂ : ℤ) :=
  { n : ℤ // x₁ ≤ n ∧ n < x₂ }
```

Now I want a function space from `zbound x₁ x₂` to `bool` packed with a proof `x₁ < x₂`, so that the range is properly represented.

```
structure bounded_f (x₁ x₂ : ℤ) :=
  (map : zbound x₁ x₂ → bool)
  (prf : x₁ < x₂)
```

The problem is now as follows. I would like to have an update function of sorts, that treats `bounded_f` as a `map` and updates it to return `true` for a particular value `x`, otherwise, and this is important, delegates functionality to the original `bounded_f`.

```
def inject_true {x₁ x₂} (x : ℤ) (f : bounded_f x₁ x₂) :
  bounded_f (min x₁ x) (max x x₂) :=
    ⟨λ⟨x', prf⟩, if x = x' then true else f.map ⟨x', sorry⟩, _⟩
```

The resulting function should have a modified definition space, namely it is no longer operating on bounded range from `x₁` to `x₂`, but rather on a range from `min x₁ x` to `max x x₂`. Intuitively, this simply extends the range as needed for the new update.

Sadly I have no idea what to put instead of `sorry` in the cases where `x` is smaller than lower bound or greater than upper bound. My problem is that Lean wants me to show:

```
x₁ ≤ x' ∧ x' < x₂
```

This is however not the case, as I'd rather want an extended range than the original one. Is there something wrong with applying `f.map` right away and do I need to... modify it somehow?

Comment: Your definition seems to be under-specified, even before translating it to Lean. If I give you a function that's defined on `[0,1)` and say that `3` should map to true as well, what _do_ you want `2` to map to?

Comment: @SebastianUllrich You're completely right, I am apparently a moron :). All of this might make sense once I extend this to a default false-ness. Thanks, I think this is the missing piece.